# Get the content of an array of labels in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to check the content of an array of labels but it not works.

To explain the program: I have 4 arrays of 4 UIlabels each one and every label contains a number in String. This function returns true if one label contains the number 16. I tried to use the function "contains" but it doesn't work because "16" it's a string and not a label.

Thanks

Example of declaration of array of labels:

```
Fila1 = [UILabel]()
```

Function Win:

```
func win() -> Bool {

    for i  in 0..<Fila1.count {

        if(Fila1[i].text == "16") {
            return true

         } else if(Fila2[i].text == "16") {
            return true

         } else if(Fila3[i].text == "16") {
            return true

         } else if(Fila4[i].text == "16") {
            return true

         } else {
            return false
         }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to remove the `else` condition that contains `return false` and the code should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you shouldn't have that `else` statement `return false`.

It should be:

```
if(Fila1[i].text == "16") {
     return true

} else if(Fila2[i].text == "16") {
     return true

} else if(Fila3[i].text == "16") {
     return true

} else if(Fila4[i].text == "16") {
      return true

} // end if here
```

You're exiting out of the loop too early. If the first element isn't what you are looking for you aren't checking the rest.